# Designing Layout like iphone in android

Tags: android, android-widget, android-layout

I want to design something like [this](http://itunes.apple.com/sg/app/dbs-shopper/id396857682?mt=8) in android..See the Buttons Bar -> New Deals, NewCoupons, New Categories.

Again see the top portion of that Buttons Bar -> Its something like horizontal scroll view.

How to design such type of layouts in android. ?

Comment: Android gives you full flexibility to achieve this kind of designs, You just need to design your layout using proper views in it.

Comment: I want some examples related to it. are  there any tutorials for this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this class http://code.google.com/p/deezapps-widgets/ for implementing a horizontal scroll view.

The buttons bar can be implemented using a TabWidget as Phonon suggests.

**To implement a button bar**

1. Call tabSpec.setIndicator(buildIndicator(tabName))
2. Build your view with something like:

   ```
   private View buildIndicator(String text) {
       final TextView indicator = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, null);
       indicator.setText(text);
       return indicator;
   }
   ```
3. tab_indicator.xml:

   ```
   <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/tab_label"
   android:layout_width="0dip"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:textColor="@color/white"
   android:gravity="center"
   android:textSize="14sp"
   android:textStyle="bold"
   android:minHeight="38dp"
   android:background="@drawable/bgtab"/>
   ```
4. bgtab is a selector drawable with

   ```
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item
       android:state_pressed="true"
       android:drawable="@drawable/bg_tab_default"
       />
   <item
       android:state_selected="false"
       android:state_focused="false"
       android:state_pressed="false"
       android:drawable="@drawable/bg_tab_default"
       />
   <item       
       android:state_selected="true"
       android:state_focused="false"
       android:state_pressed="false"
       android:drawable="@drawable/bg_tab_selected"
       />
   <item
       android:state_focused="true"
       android:state_selected="true"
       android:state_pressed="false"
       android:drawable="@drawable/bg_tab_selected"
       />
   ```

This is mostly from the Google I/O app. bg_tab_selected/default will be 9-patch PNGs which when expanded will be shaped like buttons.

Comment: How can i coustom TabWidget?..I have used TabWidget before also. How can i make TabWidget equilvalent to look that Button Bars

Comment: I am getting errors in this two lines in main.xml file :
deezapps:roundRectRadius="2dip"
deezapps:pageWidth="250dip"

Error : No Source Identifier Found for Attribute pageWidth in package com.deezapps.widget

same error for roundRectRadius..

Comment: I am not able to download all drawables..i checked this link : http://code.google.com/p/iosched/ ...

Comment: You will have to create the drawables yourself for the iPhone like look. The iosched project has all the drawables here: http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fres%2Fdrawable-hdpi%253Fstate%253Dclosed

Answer (score 1):

For the "Horizontal ScrollView", look up `ViewFlipper`. It's much more like what you're asking about. The coupons/deals/categories can be implemented with `TabWidget` (basically a tabbed view) with custom Tab images that look like buttons.

Comment: How can i coustom TabWidget?..I have used TabWidget before also. How can i make TabWidget equilvalent to look that Button Bars...