# android TabActivity - get Tab Icon from database

Tags: android

I'm new to android app development. I'm developing a TabActivity in which the images for each tab icon comes from the database. any help on how to do this is much appreciated.
thanks..

Comment: Why from the DB? cant come from drawable resources?

Comment: Had answered this for another question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432029/designing-layout-like-iphone-in-android/5435916#5435916. Might find it useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the form of `setIndicator()` that takes a `View` as a parameter, where you supply something that contains your tab icons.